# Request specific properties from Google Freebase Topic API

Tags: api, freebase, mql

I'd like to query only specific properties like "/common/topic/description", "/common/topic/image" and "/common/topic/notable_for" of a certain topic. It would be even better if I could request those properties for several topics at once. Or does it has to be just "/common/topic" filter?

**Update**
I tried this query for topic /en/the_doors   https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/the_doors?filter=(all%20/common/topic/image%20/common/topic/description)
It responds with error messege "filter is invalid: (all /common/topic/image /common/topic/description) is not a valid filter, try one of allproperties,commons,all,suggest or a schema path."

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty obvious)
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/the_doors?filter=/common/topic/notable_for&filter=/common/topic/description&filter=/common/topic/image